# R First Row Value Meets Criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data = data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
CAT=c(NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,0),
DOG=c(NA,NA,2,3,2,NA,1,NA),
MOUSE=c(2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
WANT=c(2,3,2,2,3,NA,NA,NA))
```

I have 'data' and wish to create the 'WANT' variable and what it does is it takes the first non-NA value that does not equals to '1' or '0' and it stores it in 'WANT'. The code example above shows an example of what I hope to get.

Comment: @akrun thank you for this good catch i fixed it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` after changing the values 0, 1 in the selected columns to `NA`, then bind the column with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    transmute(across(CAT:MOUSE, ~ replace(., . %in% 0:1, NA))) %>% 
    transmute(WANT2 = coalesce(!!! .)) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
#  STUDENT CAT DOG MOUSE WANT WANT2
#1       1  NA  NA     2    2     2
#2       2  NA  NA     3    3     3
#3       3   1   2    NA    2     2
#4       4   2   3    NA    2     2
#5       5   3   2    NA    3     3
#6       6  NA  NA    NA   NA    NA
#7       7  NA   1    NA   NA    NA
#8       8   0  NA    NA   NA    NA
```

---

Or using `data.table` with `fcoalesce`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop over the `.SD` `replace` the values that are 0, 1 to `NA`, use `fcoalesce` and assign (`:=`) it to create new column 'WANT2'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, WANT2 := do.call(fcoalesce, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         replace(x, x %in% 0:1, NA))), .SDcols = CAT:MOUSE]
```

---

or with `base R`, we can use a vectorized option with row/column indexing to extract the `first` non-NA element after `replace`ing the values 0, 1 to `NA`

```
m1 <- !is.na(replace(data[2:4], data[2:4] == 1|data[2:4] == 0, NA))
data$WAN2 <- data[2:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1, "first"))]
data$WANT2[data$WANT2 == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: it is perfect i will accept the answer when it allows me to do it

Comment: my last question though is how about if I wanted to be explicit with names so instead of CAT:MOUSE if only I wished for CAT and MOUSE ?

Comment: @bvowe In the first solution `across(c(CAT, MOUSE), ~ ` and in second `.SDcols = c("CAT", "MOUSE")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data$Want2 <- apply(data[,-c(1,5)],1,function(x) x[min(which(!is.na(x) & x!=0 & x!=1))])

  STUDENT CAT DOG MOUSE WANT Want2
1       1  NA  NA     2    2     2
2       2  NA  NA     3    3     3
3       3   1   2    NA    2     2
4       4   2   3    NA    2     2
5       5   3   2    NA    3     3
6       6  NA  NA    NA   NA    NA
7       7  NA   1    NA   NA    NA
8       8   0  NA    NA    0    NA
```